# Travel through every anchor and replace inner-HTML if it is something with a specific something-else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to travel through all the anchors that are descendants of the class nav (.nav) and check their content. If it is any of the cases, then replace its content with a specific and corresponding unicode.

Why isn't this working and is there a better way to do it than how I have tried?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var navigationLinks = $('.nav a');
    for(var i=0; i < navigationLinks.length; i++){
    var thisLink = navigationLinks[i];
    switch(thisLink.html()){
        case "About":
            thisLink.replace(/About/g,'&#xe00f;');

        case "Work":
            thisLink.replace(/Work/g,'&#xe010');

        case "CV":
            thisLink.replace(/CV/g,'&#xe00c');

        case "Resume":
            thisLink.replace(/Resume/g,'&#xe00d;');

        case "down":
            thisLink.replace(/down/g,'&#xe00d;');

        case "Mail":
            thisLink.replace(/Mail/g,'&#xe011;');

        case "Dribbble":
            thisLink.replace(/Dribbble/g,'&#xe015;');

        case "GooglePlus":
            thisLink.replace(/GooglePlus/g,'&#xe012;');

        case "Facebook":
            thisLink.replace(/Facebook/g,'&#xe013;');

        case "Twitter":
            thisLink.replace(/Twitter/g,'&#xe014');

        default:
            thisLink.replace(thisLink.html(),thisLink.html());
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I think you should use replace for thisLink.html() not for thisLink

Comment: @PrasathK That is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var navigationLinks = $('.nav a');
    navigationLinks.each(function() {
    var thisLink = $(this);
    switch(thisLink.html()){
        // Your code with thisLink.html();
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is more than enough .. Just use `thisLink.html()` for replace or modify like this

```
var thisLink = navigationLinks[i].html();
    switch(thisLink){
//
//
}
```

Comment: I changed it and what you said makes sense, but now I am getting an error. It says: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'html'